# Installing Embedded Linux on KIT_AURIX_TC297_TFT

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

I'm asking if there're any guide that demonstrates how to install Embedded Linux on Aurix Application Kit.

[AURIX™ Application Kit TC297 TFT](http://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/evaluation-boards/KIT_AURIX_TC297_TFT/productType.html?productType=5546d4624b0b249c014ba6c12b4d32c4#ispnTab1)

and if it's possible to do that or not.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: *"... if it's possible to do that or not."*-- Probably not since the processors are described as *"MCU"* and therefore not likely to have a MMU.  Also memory capacity is on the low side, only 728KB.

Comment: Look at this http://www.uclinux.org/description/

uClinux differs from it’s mainstream linux counterparts by having no support for memory management units (MMU)

Comment: OK, you found the variant of Linux that doesn't require an MMU.  So what?  You still have the memory issue.  And if you can't find an existing port, then it's no longer just an *"installation"* or even a build.